# Const pointers shallow copy

Tags: c++, sorting, constants, shallow-copy

is it possible to copy

```
MyStruct * const * array1
```

to

```
MyStruct * array1
```

but just as a shallow copy? I need sort it and write back into it and I want changes in array 1 too

EDIT: Im stupid, I overlooked ** at array1 then it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean const MyStruct * array1?

In any case you can use const_cast to change constness of a pointer:

```
const MyStruct * array1;
MyStruct * array2 = const_cast<MyStruct *>(array1);
```

Or

```
const MyStruct * const array1;
MyStruct * array2 = const_cast<MyStruct *>(array1);
```

Comment: The question is about `MyStruct*const`, not about `const MyStruct*`. A `const_cast<>` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Works for exactly the structure from the question... But, the second `array1` replaced with another pointer `parray`.

Maybe, you qualify this as a deep copy even if it is a shallow copy of the struct?
Then, maybe, the other answer is better.

```
struct MyStruct {
    int i;
    int* p;
};

int j=2;

MyStruct st={ 1, &j };

int main() {

    MyStruct* parray1(&st);

    MyStruct* const* array1(&parray1);

    MyStruct * parray=new MyStruct();

    parray->i = (*array1)->i;
    parray->p = (*array1)->p;
        /*
        This is essentially the same as
        (*parray) = *(*array1);
        */

    delete parray;
}
```

Edit: A second example as discussed in the comments to this answer.
Here we have a non-const pointer to which we successively assign the **pointer values** from the const pointer-pointer `array1`.

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
    int i;
    int* p;
};

int j=2;

MyStruct st1={ 1, &j }, st2={ 2, &j };

int main() {

    MyStruct* parray1[2] = {&st1, &st2};

    MyStruct* const *array1(parray1);

    std::cout << array1[0]->i << ' ' << array1[1]->i << '\n';

    MyStruct* parray=array1[0];

    parray->i = 3;

    parray=array1[1];

    parray->i = 4;

    std::cout << array1[0]->i << ' ' << array1[1]->i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The corresponding output:

```
1 2
3 4
```

---

After the last comments (I think) we have reached a common interpretation of the question.
The pointers in the const array are to be copied into a non-const array where they can be re-arranged and the objects can be modified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyStruct {
    int i;
    int* p;
};

int j=2;

MyStruct st1={ 1, &j }, st2={ 2, &j };

int main() {

    MyStruct* parray1[2] = {&st1, &st2};

    MyStruct* const *array1(parray1);

    std::cout << array1[0]->i << ' ' << array1[1]->i << '\n';

    MyStruct* parray[2];

    std::copy(array1,array1+sizeof(parray)/sizeof(parray[0]),parray);

    // some manipulation:
    std::swap(parray[0],parray[1]);

    parray[0]->i = 3;

    parray[1]->i = 4;

    std::cout << array1[0]->i << ' ' << array1[1]->i << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The new output is:

```
1 2
4 3
```

Comment: if I change i and p in parray would it change in array1 too?

Comment: No, it would not. But, *p within array1 would change if you change *p in *parray. That is because of the shallow copy of the array itself.

Comment: There was a typo in the last comment. Therefore, once more: Note, that `array1` always keeps pointing to the same pointer to some `MyStruct`. But, the `MyStruct`-object itself is not const. Therefore, it is no problem to change the data. And you can also assign the value `*array1` to `p` of type `MyStruct *p`. That is not a problem. And if you change the data in `*p` then you change it in `**array1`. Maybe, I add a second example for this case...

Comment: Omg Im stupid.. I needed ** not just *.. then I can simply copy it :)

Comment: I have changed the answer accordingly.